# How to get around this long overflow error in a loop method with conditionals?

Tags: javascript

I am still learning my way around JS and have run into this issue that I cannot figure out. I have two sets of array of json objects that I have simplified as an example here. I wrote a method to basically compare the two and make sure the values match with each other. It looks like the following:

```js
var actual = {
  "nameTag": "abc123",
  "number": "567553218",
  "hitDate": "2022-12-09"
};

var expected = {
  "nameTag": "abc123",
  "number": "567553218",
  "hitDate": "2022-12-09"
};

function matchVar(actual, expected) {
  var array = [];
  var now = new Date();
  var dateNow = new Date(now.getTime() + now.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

  for (key in actual) {
    var checkForMatch = false;
    var actualDate = Date.parse(actual[key]);
    if (isNaN(actualDate) || !(isNaN(actual[key]))) {
      if (expected.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var tempMatch = console.log("There is a match!");
      } else {
        continue;
      }
    } else {
      if (actualDate <= dateNow) {
        checkForMatch = true;
      } else {
        checkForMatch = false;
      }
    }
    array.push(checkForMatch);
  }
  return (array);
}

console.log(matchVar(actual, expected));
```

When I run the code here, it gives the correct result back. However, when I run on my local machine and/or on docker, I get the following error:

```
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: java.lang.ArithmeticException: long overflow
- java.base/java.lang.Math.multiplyExact(Math.java:1004)
- java.base/java.lang.Math.multiplyExact(Math.java:980)
- java.base/java.time.Instant.toEpochMilli(Instant.java:1236)
- com.oracle.truffle.js.runtime.builtins.JSDate.makeDay(JSDate.java:502)
- com.oracle.truffle.js.runtime.builtins.JSDate.makeDate(JSDate.java:522)
- com.oracle.truffle.js.builtins.DateFunctionBuiltins$DateParseNode.parse(DateFunctionBuiltins.java:113)
- com.oracle.truffle.js.builtins.DateFunctionBuiltinsFactory$DateParseNodeGen.execute(DateFunctionBuiltinsFactory.java:51)
```

The error seems to be happening on the "number" key in the loop. Please advise.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is custom logic is really necessary or you can go with external modules?

If yes then I'd suggest using either [lodash](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lodash-_-isequal-method/) or [microdiff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/microdiff). MicroDiff is very performant and small in size and gives you the differences between two objects or arrays. In your case if resulting diff's length is 0 that means both objects are identical! Otherwise you can use `_.isEqual` method from lodash as well

Comment: @Mr.Online unfortunately I cannot use external modules. Thank you for that suggestion though, I will keep it in mind in case we change the red tape around our framework.

Comment: MicroDiff is dependency independent, In fact its open so you can take a look at it's source code and then use that code for your usage. I also did the same, It's only around 70 lines of code and if you don't have an array of objects then you can even reduce those lines.

In short, I'm suggesting you to take a look at it's source which might help you in developing your own logic. Though you'll need a knowledge about recursion as it uses that in it's core. Hopefully this helps :)

Comment: `Date.parse` expects to parse [ISO 8610 calendar strings](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format). Therefore the number key, which is just a string containing an integer, is parsed as the date only form consisting solely of the year. That's a pretty absurdly big year and this causes the overflow.

Comment: The year 567553218 works out to about 17910555263884800000 milliseconds since the epoch, which is just a little too large for a Java long.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Noted. Thanks for pointing out the root cause. Any recommended alternative to Date.parse? new Date sounds promising?

Comment: It's not clear why you're trying to parse all three values as Dates. Are you trying to determine which value is date in the format YYYY-MM-DD? If so I think the best bet is to first check that the general form of the string is YYYYY-MM-DD, perhaps with a simple regex, and then use `Date.parse()`.